# Implement highlight in code

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Sometimes when a question is asked/answer with a pretty massive code, it would be nice if we could highlight all the occurrence of the selected string.

For example, if the code use a variable random_variable, if I select one occurrence of it, it put all the other occurrences in yellow. (like you can have in many code editor)

I think that could increase readability.

Comment: I believe a better solution would be to avoid posting massive amounts of code in questions. Questioners should aim for *the shortest code* necessary to explain or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Of course, but sometimes you don't have any other way to do. I think it is far more easier to read, even if there is 10 lines of code.

Comment: Doesn't your browser do this? If you *"find"* the appropriate variable, you may find it gets highlighted (Chrome does it, for example) - I use this all the time on SO.

Comment: We should definitely reduce the max length of questions.  Definitely.

Answer (score 4):

You can already do it manually if you use HTML.
Changed one of [my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26944373) here to bold `cout`, wherever it occurs:

> Just specialize that one function:
>
> ```cpp
> template <typename template_type> class awesome_class{
> public:
>     void some_function(void){
>         cout << "I am not of type_a and doing my normal methods";
>     }
> };
>
> template<> void awesome_class<type_a>::some_function(void){
>     cout << "I am of type_a and doing type_a specific methods";
> }
> ```
>
> Of course, if things are more complicated, you might have to use
>   inheritance and SFINAE.

```
Just specialize that one function:

<!-- language: lang-cpp -->

<pre><code>template &lt;typename template_type> class awesome_class{
public:
    void some_function(void){
        <b>cout</b> &lt;&lt; "I am not of type_a and doing my normal methods";
    }
};

template&lt;> void awesome_class&lt;type_a>::some_function(void){
    <b>cout</b> &lt;&lt; "I am of type_a and doing type_a specific methods";
}</code></pre>

Of course, if things are more complicated, you might have to use
inheritance and SFINAE.
```

Anyway, most of the time reducing the code and using the languages standard code-comments where needed is a better idea.

Comment: How would I do this for an HTML code example?

Comment: @brentonstrine: Just html-encode your code, and then substitute it between the code-tags. Naturally the highlighting-hint is only used here because this is meta, and not an appropriately tagged question on main.

Comment: So something like `<!-- langauge: lang-html --> &lt;p&gt;the problem is <b>here</b> in my HTML code.&lt;p&gt;`? Would the HTML still receive syntax hilighting?

Comment: Try it out. and you put it in the wrong place, I said between the `<code>`-tags.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't sure what 'substitute between code tags' meant. Seems to work if I wrap it in both a `<code>` and a `<pre>`. Thanks!